# RandomForest proximity between training and test

Tags: r, random-forest, proximity, multi-dimensional-scaling

Using `randomForest`, I want to create a low-level projection of the instance proximities, as produced by `MDSPlot()`. However, I not only want the training proximities, but proximities between **all** the instances (i.e. training **and** test). How can I do this?

I currently use `xtest` as argument to `randomForest()` and when I do

```
print("testProx")
print(rfmodel$test$prox)
print("trainProx")
print(rfmodel$prox)
```

I get

```
[1] "testProx"
[1] 119 239
[1] "trainProx"
[1] 120 120
```

So the distance from *test to all* is calculcated (119x239), but not from *train to all* (120x239). Instead, I only get from *train to train* (120x120). How can I get the full matrix *all to all* (239x239)?

To get the missing piece, I could copy the appropriate submatrix of *test to all* (i.e. *test to train*, 119x120) and use its transpose to plug it in to make the full matrix. But I was wondering if there was an easier way?

Comment: You'll get better answers on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Can you provide us with a reproducible example?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I edited the question. Not reproducible, but hopefully clearer.